# Scanner in Java doesn't read all my input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm developing an application that takes 4 lines of input. The first line contains N, which is the number of iterations, and the following N lines contain the data.

Here is my program:

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

   public class Principal {
static String binary;
static int count = 0;
public static void main (String args [])
{       
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int N = Integer.parseInt(s.next());
    //System.out.println(N);
    int X = 0;
    int cpt=1, test = 1;
    boolean negatif = false;
    boolean test1 = false;
    for (int i =0;i <N; i++)
    {
        X = Integer.parseInt(s.next());
        //System.out.println(s.next());
        while (cpt < 1337)
        {
            if ((cpt % 7 == 0)||(Integer.toString(cpt)).contains("7"))
            {                   
                negatif = !negatif;
            }

            if (negatif == false)
            {
                if (test == 1337)
                    test = 1;
                else
                    test++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (test == 1)
                    test = 1337;
                else
                    test--;
            }

            cpt++;
            if (cpt == X)
            {
                test1 = true;
                break;
            }

        }

        if (test1)
            System.out.println(test);

        test = 1;
        cpt=1;
        negatif = false;
        test1 = false;
    }

}
  }
```

And the input is:

```
 3
10
100
1000
```

And the output is supposed to be:

```
 4
 2
1311
```

The problem is that I cannot reach the last line which contains 1000.

Please help.

Comment: When I run the code you provided and give the input you provided, I get the output you give (minus the spaces before the first two numbers). What is the problem?

Comment: the problm is that when i run the program i just get 4 and 2 as output, the scanner doesn't read my last line

Comment: You probably didn't end it with a carriage return (press enter).